# Second order partial derivative of $\log|PWP^T|$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Let $\phi = \text{log}|PWP^T|$, where $P = J + XU^T$.

Except $W$ others are rectangular matrices. Further $W$ is positive definite.

I want to find the second partial derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $X$ and $W$. After referring some posts in the stack exchange my approach is as follows:

Let $Y = PWP^T$ and $dP = dXU^T$.

\begin{align*}
d\phi & = \operatorname{tr}[Y^{-1}(dPWP^T + PWdP^T)]\\
&= \operatorname{tr}(Y^{-1}(dXU^TWP^T + PWUdX^T))\\
\Phi = \frac{d\phi}{dX} & = 2Y^{-1}PWU
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
d\Phi & = 2(-Y^{-1}PdWP^TY^{-1}PWU + Y^{-1}PdWU)\\
\vec{d\Phi} &= 2(-U^TWP^TY^{-1}P \otimes Y^{-1}P + U^T \otimes Y^{-1}P)\vec{dW}
\end{align*}

Hence the second partial derivative w.r.t $X$ and $W$ is given by
$$
2(-U^TWP^TY^{-1}P \otimes Y^{-1}P + U^T \otimes Y^{-1}P)
$$

Is it the correct way to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to compute Hessian? or only Gradients?

Comment: @user550103 Yes. My final goal is to compute the Hessian of a quantity which involves $-log(PWP')$ as one component. Before proceeding further I want to ensure whether this is the correct way to obtain the partial derivatives.

Comment: Ok. To me, it looks good. Where do you intend to employ this?

Comment: @user550103 I found stationary points of the below objective function $log|PWP^T|+tr((PWP^T)^{-1}PVP^T)$ (taking derivatives separately w.r.t $X$ and $W$ and evaluating it at zero). Now I want to ensure that this solution is a minimizer of the above objective function. So I want to compute the Hessian and ensure that it is positive definite at the obtained solution.